# Loading JNA Native Libraries

Tags: jna, ddl

I create a Digital Signature Using USB Token but the problem is that my JNA `cannot load the DLL library`

I have tried using **JNA jar files**

```
 C.NATIVE = new JNA(library);
```

> The above codes give me error

I expect it to work if there is no error

Comment: What is the exact error? Where is the dll?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You haven't given us enough information to help -- please let us know the exact name of your library and where it is located on your system.

Comment: C.NATIVE = new JNA(String variable); Does this work?